# How can I reduce the indentation in Stack.Navigator / Stack.Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Root() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Main"
                          component={MainMenu}
                          options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Games"
                          component={Games}
                          options={{ headerShown: true,
                          }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
            <Drawer.Screen name="MainMenu" component={Root}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

I have similar navigation, but there is a big gap between Drawer and Stack, how can I reduce it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KVkY.png)

I tried to set headerStyle in options and specify height, margin and similar commands, but nothing works, since according to the documentation you can only set fontSize and FontFamily there